# Rx Java Calling Api's based on boolean values

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I am fairly new to RX java, I know how to use a zip or flat map however I have a problem as follows for which I am feeling out of options:

I have a method which I am trying to refactor :

```
updateDetails(emailAddress: String?, updateEmail: Boolean,
                                     nickName: String?, updateNickName: Boolean,
                                     avatarFile: File?, updateAvatar: Boolean)
```

Now based on each boolean inside the method I determine whether to update email, nickname, or avatar. Earleir this was achieved using if conditions and individual API calls. Is there a way I can zip or combine the calls using the supplied flags?

Comment: What does the nullability mean? `emailAddress==null` implies the email is *not* updated, or (if the flag is `true`) it is deleted?

In other words, why do you need the `update*` flags at all?

Comment: The nullability means the email id was deleted and deletion needs to be updated on server, the design is such that a user can update anyone or all of these items from a single page, that associates booleans with the fields. I know the design is not optimal but I have inherited this.

Comment: are the methods of your API calls returning an observable?

Comment: Yes each API call returns a Single<Response<ResponseBody>>, I have control on modifying this part as well. But I dont have control on how and with what params the method in question is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in a blocking fashion:

```
    fun updateDetails(emailAddress: String?, updateEmail: Boolean,
                      nickName: String?, updateNickName: Boolean,
                      avatarFile: File?, updateAvatar: Boolean) {
        if (updateEmail) {
            updateEmail(emailAddress).blockingGet()
        } 

        if (updateNickName) {
            updateNickName(nickName).blockingGet()
        }

        // ...
    }
```

or you could build the chain like this and subscribe to it in the end:

```
fun updateDetails(emailAddress: String?, updateEmail: Boolean,
                                     nickName: String?, updateNickName: Boolean,
                                     avatarFile: File?, updateAvatar: Boolean) {

        var chain = Completable.complete()

        if (updateEmail) {
            chain = chain.andThen(updateEmail(emailAddress).ignoreElement())
        }

        if (updateNickName) {
            chain = chain.andThen(updateNickName(nickName).ignoreElement())
        }

        // ...

        chain
            .subscribeOn(..)
            .observeOn(..)
            .subscribe()
}
```

or chaining completables:

```
    fun updateDetails(emailAddress: String?, updateEmail: Boolean,
                      nickName: String?, updateNickName: Boolean,
                      avatarFile: File?, updateAvatar: Boolean) {

        Completable.defer {
            if (updateEmail) {
                updateEmail(emailAddress)
                    .ignoreElement()
            } else {
                Completable.complete()
            }
        }
            .andThen(Completable.defer {
                if (updateNickName) {
                    updateNickName(nickName)
                        .ignoreElement()
                } else {
                    Completable.complete()
                }
            })
            // ...
            .subscribeOn(..)
            .observeOn(..)
            .subscribe()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Gustavo - One thing which is not clear is where and how will I fetch the results of these API calls. I know subscribe will be the place but I am unsure how!?